# Как построить график для сплайн интерполяции с помощью библиотеки matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Вот изначальный код:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

if name == 'main':
    x_points = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.3, 1.7])
    y_points = np.array([100.0, 4.0, 1.2346, 0.59172, 0.34602])

# tck : tuple (t,c,k) a tuple containing the vector of knots,
# the B-spline coefficients, and the degree of the spline.
tck = interpolate.splrep(x_points, y_points)

print("При 0,1:", interpolate.splev(0.1, tck))
print("При 0,5:", interpolate.splev(0.5, tck))
print("При 0,9:", interpolate.splev(0.9, tck))
print("При 1,3:", interpolate.splev(1.3, tck))
print("При 1,7:", interpolate.splev(1.7, tck))
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @Lol, [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

для этого достаточно создать массив точек по оси `X` и подать его на вход `interpolate.splev()`:

```
x = np.linspace(0.1, 1.7, 100)
y = interpolate.splev(x, tck)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]